# Why is Acrylic Brush Not Supported in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, acrylic-material

I have created a basic UWP app, and when I try to use the Acrylic brush like this:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="LearningUWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LearningUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
// Acrylic brush here
    <Page.Resources>
        <media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="HostBackdropBrush"
                            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                            TintColor="LightBlue"
                            TintOpacity="0.6"
                            FallbackColor="LightSkyBlue"
                            FallbackForced="False" />
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <Grid>

        <Button Content="Synthesize" Margin="528,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="93" Width="222" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="39,62,0,0" Text="Hello, World!" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Visual Studio says that `Acrylic Brush is not supported in UWP`.
I am Windows 10 1903 (which is also my target version) and my minimum version is is 1803.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do it:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
                              BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                              TintColor="Black"
                              TintOpacity="0.5"
                              TintLuminosityOpacity="1"
                              FallbackColor="#111111"
                              />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
```

By adding the above code into my `<Page>` and setting `<Grid>` Background like this:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource MyAcrylicBrush}">
```

Where `MyAcrylicBrush` is the `AcrylicBrush`'s `x:Key`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Acrylic Brush Not Supported in UWP?

[`AcrylicBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush?view=winrt-19041) is available from 16299, it could work in  1803 min version (17134), your compile error is used `media:` namespace, but you have not referred WinUI nugget package, and if your mini 1809, you have no need add `media` namespace. you just give it a `x:key` and use [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension) to refer the acrylic brush.